# How to start new line with space for next line in Html.fromHtml for text view in android

Tags: android, html

Could anyone tell me how to start new line with space for next line  in `Html.fromHtml` for text view in android?
I used `<br>` tag for next line; I can't achieve to give space because `&nbsp;` will not support in `Html.fromHtml`. can aybody tell is ther any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you try `<br/>`, `<br><br/>` or simply `\n` ? `<br>` should be supported according to this source, though.

[Supported HTML tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Answer (score 8):

`<br> &nbsp;` worked for me.

Comment: Works great for me as well.. !

Answer (score 4):

simply add  `+ "<br />" +`   is enough for a line break

Answer (score -2):

Enclose your text in 
 --Here-- with the space you want in new line.
save it in a String variable then pass it in Html.fromHtml().

Answer (score -5):

use `<br/>` tag

Example:

```
<string name="copyright"><b>@</b> 2014 <br/>
Corporation.<br/>
<i>All rights reserved.</i></string>
```